# Product Search in woocommerce rest api

Tags: rest, react-native, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

i'm working on React Native project which uses woocommerce rest api to display products on app.

is there any way to search products by user inputs through userwoocommerce rest api??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am using V3 of Rest API fo WooCommerce and doing search in my apps by using filter. The code looks like this -

```
WooCommerce.getAsync("products?filter[q]=" + this.searchQuery + "&page=" + this.page)
```

The API Syntax is: `GET /products?filter[q]=search-keyword`

So, when a User searches for red in the search bar - it takes red as query and returns results filtered with "red" keyword.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: This is what it looks when I enter red in search and create request -

```
 http://myweb.com/wc-api/v3/products?filter%5Bq%5D=red&oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxx&oauth_nonce=eupq1i8MlyxGsnAYq2bL6wg9UJALsdaX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1545985748&oauth_version=1.0&filter%5Bq%5D=red&oauth_signature=xxxxxxxx%2B0O4hyxfA%3D
```

Comment: @Parth - looks like the filter is referenced twice in Kanak's example - might be your issue...    Also, if you just want specific fields, you can add `_fields[]="sku"` to the URL: